# Loop a list url and get list resalt webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, list, url, web, browser

i have problem with webbrowser control on c#
i want my program navigate to a url from my list and than save surce page to string than go next url and again Repeat this process. below is my code and only get surce of bing ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication37
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              string[] url = new string[3] {"www.google.com","www.yahoo.com","www.bing.com" };

                web.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(web_DocumentCompleted);
                web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < url.Length; i++)
                {
                    web.Navigate(url[i]);
                }
        }

        void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string surce = web.DocumentText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what exactly are you doing with 'surce'?

Answer (score 0):

thankyou. for your answer .. now it work but program never cheak last item in array (for this array list i mean youtube website).. as you can see i put DocumentTitle in this program ...., program cheak title of all array list (with out last array) <= problem(1)...
question 2 : how can i put Each Result to another array ... i mean for this program title google in array[0] and navigate and put title bing  in array[1] and ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication37
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string[] url = new string[4] { "www.google.com", "www.bing.com","www.msn.com","www.youtube.com" };
        int currUrl = 0;
        WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            web.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(web_DocumentCompleted);
            web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

            web.Navigate(url[currUrl]);
            currUrl++;
        }

        void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        { 
            string surce = web.DocumentTitle;



            if (currUrl < url.Length)
            {
                web.Navigate(url[currUrl]);
                currUrl++;




                label1.Text += surce;





            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting only the content of "www.bing.com" because your loop continues to run before each page finishes loading, so the only page that actually raises the `DocumentCompleted` event is the last one.

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string[] url = new string[3] {"www.google.com","www.yahoo.com","www.bing.com" };
    int currUrl = 0;
    WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        web.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(web_DocumentCompleted);
        web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

        web.Navigate(url[currUrl]);
        currUrl++;
    }

    void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string surce = web.DocumentText;

        if (currUrl < url.Length)
        {
            web.Navigate(url[currUrl]);
            currUrl++;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why down vote the answer?
'Navigate' doesn't block until the document finished loading!